# Enumerate in entity creates "check" contraint when creating table

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

With the new release of springboot 3.1 I have noticed that when I create an entity with an enumerate field, the database contains checks in correspondence of that field, before was not like that. I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid this, I'm using PostgreSQL.

Here my entity class:

```
public class LogFile  {

@Column(nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Status status;

private String fileName;

}
```

Here my Status enum:

```
public enum Status {

ACTIVE("ACTIVE"),
PASSIVE("PASSIVE");

private String value;

Status(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}
}
```

When the table is created this is the SQL code that I see:

> create table log_file (status varchar(255) not null check (status in ('ACTIVE','PASSIVE')), file_name varchar(255))

Comment: Don't let hibernate create  your table (maybe for quick prototyping or tests but not in real life production use). Use flyway or liquibase to drive your database schema.

Comment: sure thing! but still

Comment: This is a change/update in Hibernate and/or the dialects (not so much anything Spring related) so you would need to check that. However I think it is just backed into the dialect.

Comment: I would say this is a great thing! https://martinelli.ch/should-you-use-enums-with-jpa/

Comment: kudos for the article @SimonMartinelli, I'm well aware but unfortunately I'm stuck with this

Comment: I had a look at the Source code but couldn't find a way to turn this feature off. I would recommend to open and issue: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/HHH/issues

Comment: Unless your database contains only ephemeral data, this is not a problem in production because you're never going to be creating the database automatically through code inference. To preserve the data, you need to *migrate* it. To do this automatically on release deployment, use a migration tool like Flyway or Liquibase etc with migration SQL scripts where you get to define exactly what you want the schema to be. Once you have that, there's no benefit to having the DB created for you even for testing.

Answer (score 1):

The enum converter (`NamedEnumValueConverter`) is hard coded but it calls Dialect to imlement the check. So, the solution is to extend your dialect.`getCheckCondition` Is called by enum converter to generate rules for values check.

```
package com.mycompany;

import org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect;

public class MyPostgresDialect extends PostgreSQLDialect {
    @Override
    public String getCheckCondition(String columnName, String[] values) {
        // We do not want enum database checks
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then somewhere in configuration you have to just specify

```
hibernate.dialect=com.mycompany.MyPostgresDialect
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable all checks I had to override two methods in the Dialect class:

```
 @Override
  public String getCheckCondition(String columnName, String[] values) {
    // We do not want enum database checks
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public String getCheckCondition(String columnName, long min, long max) {
    return null;
  }
```